# UNION TWO SELECT ON HIVE

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I have a database like that on HIVE.

```
+--------+------------------+---------+
| rating |    date_upd      | version |
+--------+------------------+---------+
| 3      | 2021-07-01 12:13 | 2.1.9   |
| 5      | 2021-07-01 10:39 | 2.2.6   |
| 4      | 2021-07-02 10:24 | 2.2.7   |
| 5      | 2021-07-02 05:37 | 3.2.4   |
| 1      | 2021-07-02 21:40 | 3.2.5   |
```

I need to send in another table the result of two SELECT. How can I merge these two into one with HiveQL?

```
SELECT substr('date_upd',1,10) as 'day',
       count(*) cnt 
FROM tbl_one 
GROUP BY
       substr(date_upd,1,10);


SELECT substr('date_upd',1,7) as 'month',
       count(*) cnt 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY
      substr('date_upd',1,7);
```

When I do it this way, it only returns the 'day' value and not the 'month' value.

```
SELECT 
      substr('date_upd',1,7) as 'month',
      count(*) cnt_month,
      substr('date_upd',1,10) as 'day',
      count(*) cnt_day
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY
      substr('date_upd',1,7),
      substr('date_upd',1,10);
```

Comment: What results do you want?  Just put `union all` between the first two queries.

Comment: It returns this error when running with:

`
SELECT ... GROUP BY substr('date_upd',1,10)
UNION ALL
SELECT ... GROUP BY substr('date_upd',1,7)
`
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException 19:5 Schema of both sides of union should match. _u1-subquery2 does not have the field day. Error encountered near token 'table_name'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what merging means to you. If you are trying to append vertically (as it sounds from the title description) you could try this:

### Vertical append:

##### UNION:

If you want to print one report immediately after the other one just do a `UNION` statement

```sql
SELECT substr('date_upd',1,10) as 'day',
       count(*) cnt 
FROM tbl_one 
GROUP BY
       substr(date_upd,1,10);

UNION -- this is the operator you are looking for

SELECT substr('date_upd',1,7) as 'month',
       count(*) cnt 
FROM tbl_one 
GROUP BY
      substr('date_upd',1,7);
```

### Horizontal append:

##### JOIN

However if you are trying to display things horizontally, you should probably go with a join based method (simpler than window functions) probably joining on month and bringing all the monht_date, and day_date columns (in case you want to actually put these columns and counts one next to another).

| day | count_day | month | count_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-01 12:13 | 2 | 2021-07 | 45 |
| 2021-07-02 11:07 | 5 | 2021-07 | 45 |
| 2021-07-05 07:22 | 3 | 2021-07 | 45 |

##### WINDOW FUNCTIONS:

If you dont want to have repetition of columns you could directly aggregate over different levels, using window functions with partition levels. But this is clearly more advanced and probably not what requested. Just pointing directions.

You would get something like:

| date | count_day | count_month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-01 12:13 | 2 | 45 |
| 2021-07-02 11:07 | 5 | 45 |
| 2021-07-05 07:22 | 3 | 45 |

Comment: In this situation it does the SELECT first, not executing the second and bringing as different queries.

Comment: I would like to bring the HORIZONTAL APPEND, but whenever I try something it complains about GROUP BY.